# c program to print the elements of a string array of an unknown size

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am trying to write a program to print out the player with maximum wins, if there is a tie, then all players with highest number of wins should be printed. The program takes the names of the players as parameters, then requests the user to enter how many games were played then the result of each match. I created a struct of players that keeps track of the player names as well as the number of games they've won. I am stuck at the tie part as my program seems to compile with a weird error as the below:

```
./playgame one two three                                                                                             
How many games? 5 
Match winner: one
Match winner: two
Match winner: two
Match winner: three
Match winner: one
one
two
AWL=)
```

I think the problem is because of the way I am storing and reading the winners. Here is the code I wrote so far for printing the winner.

```
void bestplayer(void)
{
    string winner[player_count];
    int highest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < player_count; i++)
    {
        if(players[i].wins >  highest)
        {
            highest = players[i].wins;
            winner[i] = players[i].name;
        }

        else if(players[i].wins== highest)
        {
            winner[i] = players[i].name;
        }
    }

    // print out the winner list
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(winner)/sizeof(winner[0]); j++)
    {

        printf("%s\n",winner[j]);

    }

    return;
}
```

I the example above, I should get one and two in the results. I thought it could be because it is trying to get the third element of the array which is empty, so I tried adding this statement instead but it gave me the same result.

```
// print out the winner list
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(winner)/sizeof(winner[0]); j++)
    {
        if(winner[j] != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n",winner[j]);
        }
    }
```

I suspect my issue is in the string declaration. The problem is that I don't know how many winners I would have, but the worst case scenario would be that they're all winners. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is your code really C? What is `string`? Is this a CS50 exercise?

Comment: Also why `sizeof(winner)/sizeof(winner[0])` when you already have the number of elements in `player_count`?

Comment: If you want to use printf to print a C++ string, you need to do something like:  printf("%s\n", winner[i].c_str());

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I was able to solve the problem by simplifying my approach. I was basically trying too hard with the string of arrays.

Instead, I identified the value of the most wins and stored that value in highest.
Then I used a loop to iterate through the struct and print out the names of all players whose wins match the value of highest.